# ng2-charts access base chart object

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm using [ng2-charts](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) in my ionic 2 project to draw a line chart. I need to access the chart datapoint collection in the (chartClick) event. For that I need access to the base chart.js object for the chart. Is there a way I can access the chart object?

HTML:

```
<base-chart class="chart"
        [data]="chartData"
        [labels]="chartLabels"
        [options]="lineChartOptions"
        [colours]="lineChartColours"
        [legend]="lineChartLegend"
        [chartType]="chartType"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></base-chart>
```

TypeScript:

```
chartClicked(e: any) {
    var chart = //reference to base chart object.
    var points = chart.getPointsAtEvent(e);
    alert(chart.datasets[0].points.indexOf(points[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this eventually. Used the app.getComponent() method to get a reference to the ng2-chart object and then to the internal chart.js chart object.

HTML: (added the element id 'mylinechart')

```
<base-chart id="mylinechart" class="chart"
    [data]="chartData"
    [labels]="chartLabels"
    [options]="lineChartOptions"
    [colours]="lineChartColours"
    [legend]="lineChartLegend"
    [chartType]="chartType"
    (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></base-chart>
```

Typescript:

```
constructor(private app: IonicApp) {
}

chartClicked(e: any) {
    var chartComponent = this.app.getComponent('mylinechart'); //ng2-chart object
    var chart = chartComponent.chart; //Internal chart.js chart object
    console.log(chart.datasets[0].points.indexOf(e.activePoints[0]));
}
```

**Update on 14-Feb-2017 with @ViewChild**

If the above doesn't work (due to angular updates) try this. I didn't test this exact code as I don't have the exact source code anymore. In my current project I'm using angular 2.4 so I know @ViewChild works.

Change the HTML markup to:

`<base-chart #mylinechart class="chart" etc..` (notice **#mylinechart**)

Type script:

At the top: `import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';`

And then inside your component class:

```
@ViewChild('mylinechart')
private chartComponent: any;

constructor(private app: IonicApp) {
}

chartClicked(e: any) {
    var chart = this.chartComponent.chart; //Internal chart.js chart object
    console.log(chart.datasets[0].points.indexOf(e.activePoints[0]));
}
```

Basically @ViewChild gets you a reference to the component marked by '#mylinechart' in the template. Decorating the `chartComponent` variable with `@ViewChild` makes it possible to access the chart component via that variable. Please note that references returned by `@ViewChild` are only available after 'ngAfterViewInit' life-cycle event. Since my use case is a chart 'click' event, I can safely assume that the view has been initialized by that time.

Reference: [Angular @ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child)

Comment: This didn't work for me. getComponent seems deprecated. I tried this with ViewChild, but chart is not a valid property of chartcomponent

Comment: I have posted an update to the answer with @ViewChild. Please see whether the new approach works for you and reply here. Also check whether you need to use "ngAfterViewInit" event.

Comment: I tried it like that before. But that wasn't working. But I found another way to archieve the desired result : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42212587/1093816 (Basically viewchilding BaseChartDIrectory and using its ngOnChange method to update the chart. Thanks for your feedback though!

Comment: I'm using this to access it and it works: ```@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) public chart: BaseChartDirective;``` If you need to force a refresh so the options are considered again: ```this.chart?.ngOnChanges({});```