# how to hide specific dataset based on condition chartjs angular

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have created a simple doughnut chart using chartjs plugin in angular like the given screenshot below

[image: 1]

now when the chart loads if the dataset value below 100 it should automatically hide like below

[image: 2]

here is my complete code   https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-legend-with-value-hide

tried this piece of code which was taken from this reference https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/00q06vjp/

```
pieChartData.data.forEach(function(ds) {
    ds.hidden = !ds.hidden;
```

still no luck please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Update your ngOnInit on stackBlitz and see if this is what you want

```
ngOnInit() {
    const othis = this;
    this.pieChartData.forEach((data, i) => {
      if (data < 100) {
        othis.pieChartData.splice(i, 1);
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: looks like that is not what he wants, you remove the data completely while he wants it hidden but able to show it if he clicks the legend

Comment: Yes I figured it out later

Comment: yes @LeeLenalee, this I don't want to slice the data instead i want to hide that

Comment: You need to find way with chart options. take a look at legend-item-interface https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-item-interface

Comment: You need to find way with chart options. look at https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-item-interface

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the chart object from the wrapper you can hide the dataset this way:

```
if (data < 100) {
  chartObject.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = true
  chartObject.update()
}
```

But im not fammiliar with the ng wrapper so I dont know if they exposed the chart object. If this is not the case you might want to look into using only the normal lib and writing your own wrapper component.

Edit: According to this thread it is possible to acces the chart object ([ng2-charts access base chart object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905395/ng2-charts-access-base-chart-object))

Comment: what is the chartObject @LeeLenalee https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-legend-with-value-hide I have tried it's not working

Comment: Normally when you make a chart you can put it in a variable but since you are using a wrapper around chart.js it you cant do that and need to acces that variable inside the wrapper. Thats why I added a link to another issue on how you can do it since I am not fammiliar with it. In the basic it seems like you need to put a ref on the chart in your html and then you can access the inner chartObject

Answer (score 0):

When you set your data, you probably have something like this:

```
this.barChartData = [
    { data:[1, 2, 3], label: 'legend'}
];
```

you can add one parameter entitled `hidden` :

```
this.barChartData = [
    { data:[1, 2, 3], label: 'legend', hidden: true }
];
```

instead of "true", you can probably run a test and beforehand and store the result in a variable.